# Yii2 and Bundle Url

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How can I get bundle url in a view if it was registered on the layout not in the view itself?

In the layout I have:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use app\assets\LoginAsset;
$bundle = LoginAsset::register($this);
```

And in the view I do:

```
<?php
use app\assets\LoginAsset;
$bundle = LoginAsset::register($this);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $bundle->baseUrl; ?>/img/avatar-sign.png" alt="">
```

But I want to avoid repeating bundle registration, other views use same layout but they do not need the bundle url.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use [`AssetManager::getBundle()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#getBundle()-detail)

```
$bundle = Yii::$app->assetManager->getBundle('app\assets\LoginAsset');
```